# How to handle an observable that may return empty when using switchMap RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

how should the following scenario be handled with RxJS?

I have an observable that queries my Firestore database for a submission by an ID extracted from the url parameters:

```
this.submission$ = this.db.collection$('submissions', ref => ref.where('submissionArtistUID', '==', this.artistParam));
```

For elements subscribed to this observable the `submission$` returns an array of submission objects. Thus I can use `switchMap` to query my `users` table once the `submission$` has resolved:

```
this.user$ = this.submission$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    (submissions) => {
      return this.db.collection$('users', ref => ref.where('userUID', '==', submissions[0].submissionUserUID ))
    }
  )
)
```

However, the submissions query is not guaranteed to return anything. So when I used the `switchMap` on a submission that returns empty, I cannot access the following property: `submissions[0].submissionUserUID`, and I'm shown this error in console:

`Cannot read property 'submissionUserUID' of undefined`

Which makes sense because the `submission$` resolves to an empty object before trying to be used in the return statement of the switchMap.

So how do I account for scenario like this using RxJS? Is switchMap the right thing to use? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use filter operator before switchmap. Your code might look like this.

```
this.user$ = this.submission$.pipe(
filter(submissions => Object.keys(submissions).length > 0),
  switchMap(
    (submissions) => {
      return this.db.collection$('users', ref => ref.where('userUID', '==', submissions[0].submissionUserUID ))
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: very concise, filter did the trick! Thanks for teaching me an application of that operator :)

Comment: Awesome. Glad to help